# Django how to convert the older format url to the newer format path

Tags: django, ajax

I am using ajax to create a GET request to django, and I want to convert the older format url to the newer format path.

This line works

`url(r'^setComplete/$', views.setComplete, name='setcomplete'),`

While this line fails with 404(http://127.0.0.1:8000/project/setComplete?item_id=1) Not found

`path('setComplete/<int:item_id>',views.setComplete, name='setcomplete'),`

Here is the Ajax code

```
    $.ajax(
    {
        type:"GET",
        url: "/project/setComplete",
        data:{
                 item_id: itemid
        },
        success : function(data) {
                        console.info("Success",data);
                    },
                    error : function(e) {
                        console.info("Error",e);
                    },
                    done : function(e) {
                        console.info("DONE",e);
                    }
     })
```

Here is a simple view just for testing

```
def setComplete(request):
    return HttpResponse("Success!")  # Sending an success response
```

Comment: You are not giving `itemid` as a parameter in your view. It should be `def setComplete(request,itemid)`

Comment: those two urls you typed are not same.

Comment: @KanishkTanwar I did have a typo on the first version, but i fixed it and still the same result. Or if your reffering to the $ and the <int:item_id> Im not sure how to match them to be the same

Comment: @ManasKinkar You are right, but either way I get this error jquery.min.js:4 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/project/setComplete?item_id=1&result=true 404 (Not Found)

Comment: what does `&result=true` mean? if you want result as well then add that as a parameter in view

Comment: @ManasKinkar Sorry, I was trying something different, but here is the correct error:
 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/project/setComplete?item_id=1 404 (Not Found)

Comment: oh okay, you are passing it as data, so no need to give any parameter in view and also in URL. you can access the data using `request.GET['itemid']` in view. the URL should be `path('setComplete',views.setComplete, name='setcomplete'),`

Comment: @ManasKinkar Thank you very much, I finally figured it out and posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help and comments.

Here is the answer for anyone else stuck.

**Option 1**

Using the same path

`url(r'^setComplete/$', views.setComplete, name='setcomplete'),`

becomes

`path('setComplete/<int:item_id>',views.setComplete, name='setcomplete'),`

and

```
    $.ajax(
    {
        type:"GET",

        url: "/project/setComplete/" + itemid,
```

**Option 2** Or keeping the same structure like this:

`url(r'^setComplete/$', views.setComplete, name='setcomplete'),`

becomes

`path('setComplete/',views.setComplete, name='setcomplete'),`
and

```
    $.ajax(
    {
        type:"GET",

        url: "/project/setComplete/",
        data:{
                 item_id: itemid,
        },
```

Also here is a useful resource on the topic.
[Django 2.0 cheatsheet](https://consideratecode.com/2018/05/02/django-2-0-url-to-path-cheatsheet/)